# How to Dissolve by any attribute in geotools

Tags: geotools, dissolve, jts-topology-suite

Just like in ArcGIS we have dissolve option by any field. How can we do the same operation using GeoTools/JTS on any attribute.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Sure,I understand. Will post my solution what i tried and where i got stucked

Answer (score 1):

The basic principal is simple you go through the features extracting all the geometries for each value of the attribute, form them into a `GeometryCollection` and then `union` the collection together.

```
static final FilterFactory2 FF = CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory2();
  static final GeometryFactory GF = new GeometryFactory();

  public static SimpleFeatureCollection dissolve(SimpleFeatureCollection features, String attribute) {
    //First find out the values to dissolve on
    SimpleFeatureType schema = features.getSchema();
    Class<?> type = schema.getDescriptor(attribute).getType().getBinding();
    HashSet<Object> types = new HashSet<>();
    try (SimpleFeatureIterator itr = features.features()) {
      while (itr.hasNext()) {
        SimpleFeature f = itr.next();
        Object v = f.getAttribute(attribute);
        types.add(v);
      }
    }
    //build the output schema
    SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder ftb = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
    ftb.add("id", Integer.class);
    ftb.add(attribute, type);
    GeometryDescriptor geometryDescriptor = schema.getGeometryDescriptor();
    String geomName = geometryDescriptor.getLocalName();
    ftb.setName("Dissolved");
    ftb.add(geomName, geometryDescriptor.getType().getBinding(),
        geometryDescriptor.getCoordinateReferenceSystem());
    SimpleFeatureType outSchema = ftb.buildFeatureType();
    SimpleFeatureBuilder builder = new SimpleFeatureBuilder(outSchema);
    // collect the output features
    ArrayList<SimpleFeature> output = new ArrayList<>();
    int i = 0;
    // for each type
    for (Object value : types) {
      PropertyIsEqualTo filter = FF.equals(FF.property(attribute), FF.literal(value));
      // fetch the matching features
      try (SimpleFeatureIterator itr = features.subCollection(filter).features()) {
        // collect the geometries
        ArrayList<Geometry> geoms = new ArrayList<>();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
          SimpleFeature f = itr.next();
          geoms.add((Geometry) f.getDefaultGeometry());
        }
        // make a collection of the geometries
        GeometryCollection coll = GF.createGeometryCollection(GeometryFactory.toGeometryArray(geoms));
        // dissolve any that overlap
        Geometry geom = coll.union();
        // build an output feature
        builder.set(attribute, value);
        builder.set("id", i);
        builder.set(geomName, geom);
        SimpleFeature outFeature = builder.buildFeature(null);
        output.add(outFeature);
      }
    }
    return DataUtilities.collection(output);
  }
```

Here are the before and after shapefiles I tested on:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for you help. This really helped

Comment: @gizmogaurav Please do not add thanks comments. Instead, upvote and accept the answer, as per the Help doc [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Taking the [Tour] might help as well.

Comment: I think using https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/operation/union/CascadedPolygonUnion.html would be better, right?

Comment: I'd need to run some tests to see which is quicker, I think that one needs to build an index.